# Why do we use $input = Input::all(); in our php when we are giving inputs

Tags: php, laravel

What is the use of these steps in a PHP code. In my code I use to create a login page where username and passwords are inputs but I did not understand why the following step is used.

```
 $input = Input::all();
```

Comment: `Input::all()` gets all the fields from your form upon submit. So, your `$input` variable will have array of fields from the form. eg: `['name'=>'John', 'email'=>'john@doe.com']`.

Comment: why we keep " :: " because i am familiar with using " -> ".

Comment: `::` means, its a static class. In L5 and above, `Inut::all()` is no longer used. Instead, you can use `$request->all()` or `Request::all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input::all()` gets all the fields from your form upon submit. So, your `$input` variable will have array of fields from the form. eg: `['name'=>'John', 'email'=>'john@doe.com']`

`Inut::all()` is no longer used. Instead, you can use `$request->all()` or `Request::all()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry If I repeated, 
`Input::all()` is to accept all requested data, but is not a good way for login page.
I recommend to use `Request $request` in your Controller and get only specified input that you expect, especially for login.
You can use:

```
$input = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
```